# codeblock font in browser is not displaying correctly

Tags: browser, fonts, code-blocks

All my browsers are displaying monospace / codeblocks in a weird ugly font and very difficult to read. I have no idea on what is causing it.

I'm using Windows 10, and it is the same across Firefox, Chrome, Edge

[image: screen capture of the font displaying ugly]

Comment: Have you tried changing the default monospaced font in Chrome, and seeing what happens?

Comment: Yes I've tried that under 'Fixed-width font' setting in Chrome which I change to Courier New. But it has no effect. The ugly font also appears when I use Firefox.

Comment: Does this appear at _all_ sites with code ([take a look e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54447096/3439404)) **or** only at https://archive.li/ItL7C (or https://archive.li/AgjyC ) and similar obscure sites?